# Why am I unable to get sever time?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Demonstration</title>
<style>
.displaybox {
width:150px;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:2px solid #000000;
padding:10px;
font:24px normal verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
//<%=new java.util.Date()%>

function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (err1) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (err2) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (err3) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return req;
}
var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();

function getServerTime() {
    var myurl = 'http://localhost/csp 2/telltimeXML.php';
    myRand = parseInt(Math.random() * 999999999999999);
    // var modurl = myurl+"?rand="+myRand;
    http.open("GET", myurl, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function useHttpResponse() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.status == 200) {
            var timeValue = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("timenow")[0];
            alert(timeValue);
            document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = timeValue.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#cccccc"
 onLoad="getServerTime()">
<center>
<h1>Ajax Demonstration</h1>
<h2>Getting the server time without page refresh</h2>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Get Server Time"
 onClick="getServerTime()">
</form>
<div id="showtime" class="displaybox"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for the PHP file:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>" .date('H:i:s')."</timenow></clock1>"; ?>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What's actually happening? Can you include the PHP code?

Comment: Can we see the php script `telltimeXML.php`?

Comment: Verify that the response actually contains the expected XML, and that it is received at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could be lots of things, since as others have pointed out we'd like to know what you are seeing.  But one guess is that the url you are requesting is not hosted on the same server as the html file.  That is, the html page you are one should be on http://localhost/.

Comment: @alex:<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>" .date('H:i:s')."</timenow></clock1>";
?>
this is code of telltimeXML.php,i have tried by having both the files in var/www folder ie this file and html page (client) to access contents ie time from server side by sending http request

Comment: @kevingessner: actually i wanna get server time through http request and the code for that i have posted...i the div box ..it time should be displayed by clicking the button..

Comment: @geon: how can we check that response contain expected XML

Comment: does it work if you just enter the url in the browser (as opposed to using javascript/xmlhttprequest)?  what comes back?

Comment: yup the time is displayed wen i type http://localhost/telltimeXML.php in my web browser